# Pointer initialization string literals

Tags: c, initialization, stack-overflow, string-literals

Let's say I have a function that I need to call a couple of times which takes a string literal as its first and only parameter. Like so:

```
func( "things_i_like\\turtles\\fresh_water" );

/* some code */

if ( turtleFred.mood == happy )
{
    func( "things_i_like\\turtles\\fresh_water" );
}

/* more code */

func( "things_i_like\\turtles\\fresh_water" );
```

Now if I would ever need to change that string literal I will have to change it in 3 different places. If I would make a typo in one of the string literals while changing them, something bad could happen. To avoid that I could use a variable to store the location of the string literal. Like so:

```
const char* turtlesPath = "things_i_like\\turtles\\fresh_water";

func( turtlesPath );

/* some code */

if ( turtleFred.mood == happy )
{
    func( turtlesPath );
}

/* more code */

func( turtlesPath );
```

I have 3 problems with this approach. Let's assume instead of one string literal I have about 20-30.

**Problem #1:**
If all the pointers that hold the locations of the string literals are initialized as they are defined, thus at the beginning of the scope. And the program enters a condition which will never use these string literals, does that mean that the code that was executed to assign the string literals to the pointers (initialization) was unnecessary and wasteful?

**Problem #2:**
If the pointers that hold the locations of the string literals are defined and initialized within a callback function that could be called recursively, wouldn't that have a significant impact on the storage space of the stack?

What I specifically mean with that is: It might be not a problem at all when only using a couple of pointers that hold locations to string literals but it could become a problem when using a lot of them. Thus, when adding more and more pointers, it could eventually lead to a stack overflow.

And next to that, wouldn't that mean that the pointers will have to be initialized each time the function is called? What if there're a lot of them and the function is called thousands of times a day, wouldn't that generate a lot of overhead?

**Problem #3:**
A possible solution would be to use macros for the string literals, like so:

```
#define TURTLES_PATH "things_i_like\\turtles\\fresh_water"
```

But this seems like a not-so-very-great thing to do.

It feels like I'm missing out on something. Some suggestions or a general approach of how to deal with this would be highly appreciated. Refactoring could be used to avoid the problem to some extent but it doesn't provide a solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to suspect that variables of the form

```
const char *turtlesPath = "things_i_like/turtles/fresh_water";
```

have hidden overhead relative to putting the string literals inline, which will become significant if you need thousands of them.  You are not right about *what that overhead is*, though.  It is not runtime initialization operations nor is it stack space.  It is a thing called *dynamic relocations*, which I cannot explain concisely, I can only point you at an entire book: *[Linkers and Loaders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960)* by John Levine.

The best fix is, in fact, to use `#define` macros in a header file,

```
#define turtlesPath "things_i_like/turtles/fresh_water"
```

None of the drawbacks of C preprocessor macros apply to this particular usage, and none of the alternatives give the compiler as much freedom to optimize.

---

P.S. Don't put spaces on the inside of your parentheses.  When you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses it makes the baby Jesus cry.